# Remove an item from a dictionary when one of its keys exists in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
A = {(1, 1, 1): 2, (1, 2, 1): 1, (3, 3, 2): 1, (1, 4, 2): 1, (2, 5, 2): 3}
```

Let us assume a list B as follows:

```
B = [1 4]
```

Now, I would like to eliminate those items in dict A that their second key elements exist in the list. If I want to do the same thing for dict A based on list B, the result would be as follows:

```
C = {(1, 2, 1): 1, (3, 3, 2): 1, (2, 5, 2): 3}
```

Comment: Pls elaborate on the filtering method, which elements are to be omitted?

Comment: In this example, my focus was on the second key element. As you can see, numbers 1 and 4 (in list B) appear in the second key element of the first and fourth items in dict A. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is remove items from the dictionary if the middle element of the tuple, which forms the key, is in list `B`. Or, conversely, keep items where the middle element of the key is **not** in `B`.

You can do it like this:

```
A = {k: v for k, v in A.items() if k[1] not in B}
```